# Implement Alphabet bar for scroll support in Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I have a long list of items organized in an `ion-list` . To support the user to scroll to a specific item I would like to add an alphabet bar (not sure what is is officially called) similar to what Apple's music app has for instance.

How can this be done? Does a native plugin for this exist already? Not sure what to search for here.[image]

Comment: I have no experience with ionic, but quick searching comes up with this: https://github.com/aquint/ion-alpha-scroll

Comment: Oh thanks, this is for an older version, looks like ionic1 where ionic5 is now the stable release. But yes, thanks for confirming its called alpha scroll, found few more hits.

Comment: You can try this plugin: `https://github.com/sirius2013/ionic4-alpha-scroll`